# Decoupling higher order actions

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, field-theory, modified-gravity

I’m dealing with non-minimally coupling Quadratic gravity in the weak field limit, and as a result of the perturbation $g_{\mu\nu}= \eta_{\mu\nu} +h_{\mu\nu}$ I get some kinetic term mixing. On doing the expansion to quadratic order in $h$ I obtain an action which has couplings between a matter field $\phi$ and the gravitational spin-$0$ $h_f$ field at first order in $\Box$ operators. A schematic Lagrangian is given by,

$$\mathcal{L}=h_f\Box^2h_f+4h_f\Box h_f-2h_f\Box \phi +4\phi\Box\phi +m^2\phi ^2$$

I’ve defined a kinetic mixing matrix in order to diagonalisle the kinetic terms but this messes up the mass term and the second order box term. Does anyone have any suggestions?